# Controlling the point opacity value & threshold in volumetrics VDB

Tags: volumetrics

I'm trying to duplicate 3D density plots from Mathematica into Blender. Within Mathematica, You can control the opacity threshold of rendered points - points with value below and above the threshold are rendered with specific opacity (look at picture).

To visualise my problem I construced an 3D array of sin(x)*cos(y)*sin(z) values (it is just en example - in reality my values are strictly numeric). As You can see in Mathematica, You can define a threshold and two opacity - in this case, points which have values between ~0.5 and -0.5 are fully transparent, and points with values above - fully opaque. There is also a color ramp which defines the points color based on their values.
[image]

I reproduced the data in Blender scripting with numpy, and then write a VDB file and imported it:

```
import bpy
import pyopenvdb as vdb
import numpy as np

Volume = []
start = -5
stop = 5
step = 0.2
for i in np.arange(start, stop, step):
    for j in np.arange(start, stop, step):
       for k in np.arange(start, stop, step): 
           Volume.append(np.sin(i)*np.cos(j)*np.sin(k))
length = len(np.arange(start, stop, step))       
Volume=np.array(Volume)
Volume = Volume.reshape(length,length,length)

grid = vdb.FloatGrid()
grid.copyFromArray(Volume.astype(float))

grid.gridClass = vdb.GridClass.FOG_VOLUME
grid.name = 'density'

vdb.write("D:/test.vdb",grid)
bpy.ops.object.volume_import(filepath="D:/test.vdb", files=[])
```

Even without any shader, not all points are rendered, so somehow Blender decides which points render, and which not. There is an Clipping property in Volumetric properties tab, but still it works a little bit strange (here only Principle Volume shader is added):

[image]

**My question is:**
Is there any possibility to tweak the parameters of point opacity in Volumetric VDB data and how to control the point color based on points' value, as in Mathematica?

Or even it does't have to be with VDB, any other kind of importing volumetric into blender is ok.

[image]